# How can I test whether an allocator is using std::allocate for memory allocation?

Tags: c++, allocator

I want to provide specialized optimizations for allocations done with `std::allocator`, but if someone has subclassed it *without* overriding `allocate` or `deallocate`, then I don't know how to detect whether they're still using `std::allocator` or not.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they haven't defined their own `allocate` and `deallocate` functions, then one way to test is by testing the value

```
is_default_allocator_allocation<allocator_type>::value
```

to test whether the `allocate` and `deallocate` methods are the default ones.

If they *have* provided their own functions, then there is no generic way to test.

This solution does **not** look at the other methods.
It can give you occasional false negatives, but should not give false positives.

My implementation:

```
template<class Ax> char (&is_default_deallocate(void (std::allocator<typename Ax::value_type>::*)(typename Ax::pointer, typename Ax::size_type)))[1];
template<class Ax> char (&is_default_deallocate(void (Ax::*)(typename Ax::pointer, typename Ax::size_type)))[2];
template<class Ax> char (&is_default_allocate(typename Ax::pointer (std::allocator<typename Ax::value_type>::*)(typename Ax::size_type, void const *)))[1];
template<class Ax> char (&is_default_allocate(typename Ax::pointer (Ax::*)(typename Ax::size_type, void const *)))[2];

template<class Ax>
struct is_default_allocator_allocation  // tests allocate() and deallocate()
{
    static bool const value =
        sizeof(is_default_deallocate<Ax>(&Ax::deallocate)) == sizeof(char)
        && sizeof(is_default_allocate<Ax>(&Ax::allocate)) == sizeof(char);
};
```